# Can a cordova app get its own storage shortcut in Android Files app menu, similar to Drive?

Tags: android, cordova, storage, file-sharing

On iOS, cordova-plugin-file allows 'cordova.file.documentsDirectory' as file system layout, to generate a dedicated storage for my app in the system's file browser in the 'on my iPhone' environment. But unfortunately this file system layout is NOT available for Android.

I'm currently using cordova.file.externalDataDirectory as a system layout, which is accessible to the Files app, but (due to Scoped Storage) only has limited accessibility, as it is located to the Android/data/ folder, meaning you can't use the Files app to copy files into that environment.

So, is there a way for cordova apps to simply create a shared storage shortcut in the Files app menu, that's fully accessible to my app, but also the 'Files' app, i.e. like this:

[image: What I'm looking for]

Comment: Your app should expose a documents provider for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or other actions.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps for the quick response. No idea how to build a documents provider, but I guess it's time to learn it